# Vim in Windows using cmder line highlighting on scroll

Tags: windows, vim, cmder

UPDATE 16-02-29:
I managed to fix this error by trying to build from the sources hosted on github.  Building this way worked but I suspect the fix had something to do with either me downloading powershell 4.0 or Microsoft Build Tools 2015, because I was prompted to update after starting cmder and the bug was still gone even after update.  The fix might have also been from editing the init.bat file to point to my manual install of the latest conemu before building.  I'm not sure.

ORIGINAL POST:
I'm following a tutorial to setup vim on my Windows machine.  I have a weird bug though where when I scroll down on a file in Vim, every other line gets highlighting and will go away if I move the cursor up to those lines.

Like this:

[image]

This seems like a screen refresh issue of some kind.  There's a similar problem, not sure if related, where sometimes when I got back to cmder after quitting vim the prompt will be placed in the middle of the previous outputs and will start to overwrite these previous lines as commands are executed.  This is fixed either by a `cls` or restarting cmder.

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPtJ4TquQZY

Comment: Hard to know exactly what the bug is without knowing more about your setup, but: In the short term: try the `^L` vim command.  
Configuring/replacing your terminal emulator (e.g. Git Bash, Console2) might also help.

Comment: Just tried it in Bash and indeed the highlighting bug is gone.  So it's definitely a cmder problem.

Comment: After trying many things I think this is an issue with compatibility between cmder and vim.  When I changed the path to use the default vim that comes with git I got an entirely new set of bugs where the whole vim screen is grey and appears to be highlighted at all times.

Comment: You have not even posted the build number of ConEmu!

Comment: Good observation Maximus.  I found I'm using an alpha release of ConEmu but I just downloaded the stable version.  However I can't figure out how to change to this new ConEmu install in the cmder settings.  I looked for something in init.bat and couldn't find anything in there either.  Any ideas?